# read / write from sim card for android

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, sim-card

I've been trying to read/write from sim card but still there's no luck.

here's my code so far:

```
    //read from sim
public String adding() {
        Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn/"); 
        Cursor cursorSim = this.getContentResolver().query(simUri, null, null,null, null);
        String b = "";

        while (cursorSim.moveToNext()) {           

      b+=   (cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("name")));
        b += "\n" + (cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("_id")));      
       b+=   "\n" + (cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("number")));
        }


    return b;


}
```

//to write to sim

```
public void testing4() {
           ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

           values.put( "tag", "test" );

           values.put( "number", "1234" );

           getContentResolver().insert( Uri.parse("content://icc/adn/"); , values

    );  

    }
```

please let me know if you know something about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is some misspelling in the writing to usim.

```
getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://icc/adn"), values);
```

Also the permission should be added in the AndroidManifest.

(Side question)
In the simsalabim's source code, I don't know the meaning of the class variable "Contact".
I can't find the package which can be imported. In the eclipse, there are errors in the "Contact" lines.

The source code says that the file `content://icc/adn` is for the android version over 1.6, for 1.5 `content://sim/adn`.

(Side result)
I found the size of "number" field can be over 64 characters. In the read process, the correct value can be retrieved.
But the real phone screen can't show the full characters.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the permissions to the `AndroidManifest`?

You should have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
```

You can also get some ideas from [simsalabim](http://code.google.com/p/simsalabim/)'s source code.

Comment: I'm joining this problem. Did you solved that problem yet? I've solved import, if you're interested